# IOS Scrollable View inside another ScrollView

Tags: uitableview, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, ios8.3

I need to implement this screen and I wonder if anyone can help me with ideas to solve some scenarios, basically the screen will contain a parallax effect in the top image, the entire screen must be scrollable, the problem I am faced when designing this screen It is the way I see I need to have a scrollview and a tableview that generates me the trouble of having the scrolls in the same direction.

I've read several post here about the problem of having scroll inside scroll for example: [Nested UITableView inside another nested table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749870/nested-uitableview-inside-another-nested-table) , and what I want are actually ideas that can help me implement the screen below.

I just need suggestions of good practice, no one needs to worry about post code unless some lib to help with the problem or something.

I appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved my problem, I implemented a solution based on [ParallaxTableView](https://github.com/andersonacs/ParallaxTableView) and [is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell)

And here is my project : [UITableViewHeader](https://github.com/andersonacs/UITableViewHeader)

Comment: I was with a similar problem, tks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick on that (**DEPENDS IF YOU REALLY WANT THAT BEHAVIOR**) is having the image on the table view header. there are plenty of tutorials on github with sample implementation also.

e.g [that one](https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader)

Comment: Yeah I saw these tutorials but this is just a part of problem, the problem more complex is the table below of header with side  margins.